# Gdb - Loop detection in callstack

Tags: c++, gdb

I often have to debug coredumps of processes that have been killed after spending too much time in a particular function. A frequent cause of such behaviour is that some input container is larger than usual causing an explosion of loop iterations somewhere in the callstack.

Now my question: Is there a way - possibly a script - to detect all loops the thread is in in all stackframes at the point when it crashes? Maybe even show the progress of said loops?

Regards

Comment: Hi, maybe you can provide more details? how this function loop or deal with the container? if i understanding you right so you have more than one process and all of them crashing in this function, so it's a suspicious function and worthy to check it again plus how you manage the process.

Comment: I don't think this is possible: how do _you_ detect that some call frame is inside a loop? Can you describe the _algorithm_ you use? If you can't, then GDB can't implement such algorithm either.

Comment: In theory gdb can have access to the corefile, the binary with debug info and the sourcecode. I cannot rule out that there is a script or a compiler flag that can fill in the necessary info for gdb.